# How to turn hot observable and single into cold observable

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I try to make rx wrapper for NuProcess, library for asyncronous execution of external processes.

Here main class - "communication" with process. Here I read stdout:

```java
static class MyProcessHandler extends NuAbstractProcessHandler {

    final PublishSubject<String> stdout = PublishSubject.create();

    @Override
    public void onStdout(ByteBuffer buffer, boolean closed) {
        if (!closed) {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(bytes);
            stdout.onNext(new String(bytes));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onExit(int statusCode) {
        if (statusCode != 0)
            stdout.onError(new RuntimeException("non zero code"));
        else
            stdout.onComplete();
    }
}
```

Here how I starting process:

```java
static class Streams {

    RxProcessHandler handler = new RxProcessHandler();

    Single<Integer> waitDone(long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        return Single.create(emitter -> {
            NuProcessBuilder b = new NuProcessBuilder("some cmd");
            b.setProcessListener(handler);
            NuProcess process = b.start();
            emitter.setCancellable(() -> process.destroy(true));
            int code = process.waitFor(timeout, timeUnit);
            emitter.onSuccess(code);
        });
    }

    public PublishSubject<String> stdOut() {
        return handler.stdout;
    }

}
```

And finally my api. As you can see, here three variants:

1 - just wait process ends
2 - same with stdout callback
3 - read stdout until process ends. onComplete means zero exit code, error - nonZero exit code. `subscribe()` should start process.

I have no idea how implement 3d variant.

```java
static class PublicApi {

    //just wait process ends
    public Single<Integer> asWaitDone(long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        return new Streams().waitDone(timeout, timeUnit);
    }

    //wait process ends and have stdout callback
    public Pair<Single<Integer>, Observable<String>> asWaitDoneWithStdout(long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        Streams streams = new Streams();
        return new ImmutablePair(streams.waitDone(timeout, timeUnit), streams.stdOut());
    }

    //read stdout until process ends
    public Observable<String> asStdout(long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        return ???
    }

}
```

Comment: This makes no sense. Why not simply use `intervalRange` to get 10 numbers whenevery you have a subscriber?

Comment: Because, it's "fake" implementaion, just for question, so someone will able to reproduce it. With it, I show my contract "PublishSubject + Single  =???=>  Cold Observable"

Comment: The more closely you describe your problem the more likely you get a proper answer. PublishSubject + Single -> Cold makes no sense. You turn hot source cold by creating them on demand, but your example does not imply why you want to do it in the first place. Please describe what your original requirement is, not that you think you can solve it by PublishSubject + Single -> Cold.

Comment: Completely rewrote the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rearrange the existing set of commands and make them into an Observable

```java
static final class MyProcessHandlerObservable extends NuAbstractProcessHandler {

    final ObservableEmitter<String> emitter;

    MyProcessHandler(ObservableEmitter<String> emitter) {
        this.emitter = emitter;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStdout(ByteBuffer buffer, boolean closed) {
        if (!closed) {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(bytes);
            emitter.onNext(new String(bytes));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onExit(int statusCode) {
        if (statusCode != 0) {
            stdout.onError(new RuntimeException("non zero code: " + statusCode));
        } else {
            stdout.onComplete();
        }
    }
}

public Observable<String> asStdout(long timeout, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    return Observable.create(emitter -> {
        MyProcessHandlerObservable handler = new MyProcessHandlerObservable(emitter);
        NuProcessBuilder b = new NuProcessBuilder("some cmd");
        b.setProcessListener(handler);
        NuProcess process = b.start();
        emitter.setCancellable(() -> process.destroy(true));
    })
    .takeUntil(Observable.timer(timeout, timeUnit).map(v -> throw new TimeoutException()));
}
```